My custom permission isn't blocking put requests for editing objects
I have this permission class
class AuthorOrReadOnly(BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        return obj.author == request.user

And this viewset
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    permission_classes = (AuthorOrReadOnly, )
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    def list(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(self.queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.validated_data['author'] = request.user
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=201)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        post = get_object_or_404(self.queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(post)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def update(self, request, pk=None):
        post = get_object_or_404(self.queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(post, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)

    def partial_update(self, request, pk=None):
        post = get_object_or_404(self.queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(post, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)

    def destroy(self, request, pk=None):
        post = get_object_or_404(self.queryset, pk=pk)
        post.delete()
        return Response(status=204)

And when I open my view url route It hidden the input fields for put patch... etc methods. But when I make a request from shell it just edit any objects. So I think my permission isnt working.
I already tried put permission in list and a tuple and tried combining with other permissions, changing has_permission func, but It looks like it didnt work at all.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Your implementations does not check the .has_object_permission(…), which is not that much of a problem here, since there is no checking necessary, but if later mix in other permissions, security vulnerabilities can occur.
You can work with a ModelViewSet [drf-doc], which implements all boilerplate logic here:
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (AuthorOrReadOnly,)
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer

    # no list()
    # no create()
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.validated_data['author'] = self.request.user
        super().perform_create(serializer)

    # no retrieve()
    # no update()~
    # no partial_update()
    # no destroy()

I didn't get it. How could you return obj.author if has_permission don't receive it

@Sifirus: sorry, self.request.user.

I mean in BasePermission

@Sifirus: ah, ok. Well exactly because of the second problem: you implement custom view functions, and there you did not check the permission, essentially nullifying the permission_classes.

Is this even possible to use has_object_permission in a ViewSet (not model based)

The model based viewset works fine btw

@Sifirus: if it is not model-based? No, permission checks are hooked in the .get_object method, so if you write custom logic to get the object, it will not enforce permissions.

So I always have to use ModelViewSet? If I want to use has_object_permission.

@Sifirus: any APIView (or ViewSet) has also a .check_object_permissions(request, object) that you can invoke if you have an object in your view you want to check, this is essentially what .get_object(..) calls.

So why .get_object wasn't working in my case?

@Sifirus: you don't use .get_object(..), but get_object_or_404(self.queryset, pk=pk). The self.get_object essentially does the same, but after it retrieved the object, it checks object permissions.
